# Which permission does app needs to access gallery image and upload it to online?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-permissions, ios-permissions

My React Native 0.66 app needs to access the gallery images and upload it to online if a user decides to do so. There are 3 permissions in Android related to gallery image access and I am not clear about the exact usage of each permission:

```
PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA; 
PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
```

In android, does the app needs to request all 3 permissions one by one? Or just need to request `PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA` and other 2 will come along by themself. Permissions in `IOS` are different and what is permission in `IOS` for access gallery image and upload? I plan to use `react-native-permissions` to manage the permission in both Android and IOS.

Comment: It only needs INTERNET prrmission.

Answer (score 1):

> needs to access the gallery

I you dont need to write no need for the `PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;` . I would also throw in the internet permissions.